# how do I permanently subtract?

Tags: php

I have been practicing my php lately, and I have run into a little problem which I don't know how to fix.
I'm trying to change a number "permanently" by subtracting from it.

```
$hp = 100;

if ($monsterSort == 1) {
     $monster = "a horrible demon, you choose to fight it and lose 5hp.";
     $hp -= 5;
```

how do I make it so that $hp will become 95 instead of 100?

Comment: If you need data that changes in a way such as this - then it does not really belong directly into your code in the first place; it should be stored externally (database, flat file), and be read from there.

Comment: That is what your code already does, it's permanently subtracted from the variable until the script ends. When you run the script again, the variable starts at `100` again. To get around this, you need to store the value somehow and call it when the script runs.

Comment: Likely `hp` needs to be initialized as 100 in session, cookie, or db, then read from there, not code.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$hp` after subtracting?

Comment: solved the problem \o/. I used: if (!isset($_SESSION['hp'])) {$_SESSION['hp'] = 100;} This way it will only make the variable the first time the page is loaded.  thanks for the help <3